# Problems exporting model functions with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm struggling with creating model functions for Mongoose models. I define a method here:

```
Schema.listingSchema.method('applyPrice', function() {
  this.price = priceFromString(this.title);
});
```

and I access it here:

```
var listing = new Listing();

// assign all relevant data
listing.title = title;
...

// pull the price out of the title and description
listing.applyPrice(listing);
```

where

```
Listing = mongoose.model('Listing', Schema.listingSchema);
```

and I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Object #<model> has no method 'applyPrice'
```

Can anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining your schema? Usually you would do something like this:

```
var listingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String
});
listingSchema.method('applyPrice', function() {
  this.price = priceFromString(this.title);
});

mongoose.model('Listing', listingSchema);
var Listing = mongoose.model('Listing');

var listing = new Listing({ title: 'Title' });
listing.applyPrice();
```

Comment: Yes, that is how I define the schema, though it's in a separate file, hence Schema.listingSchema. My models have been working great for a while, until trying to add the middleware function. I added another line to initialize the schema separately from the Listing definition, still getting the same error. Do you see a difference between what I'm doing and what you've got there?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a very similar issue where I can't access model functions when they are put in a separate file.